# Thinkpad L14 G4 AMD Keyboard backlight slider is not displaying proper value under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, brightness, thinkpad, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I have a problem with my new Thinkpad where the backlight works but the 3 states are not properly shown on the slider when pressing FN+Spacebar. They're off by one, as in the keyboard backlight will be off when the slider is filled, dimly lit when it is empty and fully lit when the slider is halfway full. This is more of an annoyance than a problem since the backlight works but I'd like to fix it if possible.

When checking
`/sys/class/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight` I see `brightness` and `hw_brightness_changed` having different values (i.e. offset by one as described above) so I assume this is part of the problem.

I have tried

```
$ modprobe -r thinkpad_tpacpi
$ modprobe thinkpad_tpacpi
```

but this just led to me not seeing any slider at all until I rebooted. Manually setting brightness doesn´t work either as pressing Fn+Spacebar returns to previous values.